# Insert multiple columns into a mapped 1-1 single column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following setup in SQL Server 2016. I want to insert into table B name, surname, address into there respective columns, but from the 3 columns in View A for employment, I want to insert a single row for each person based on their Employment into Employment Status column in Table B, What is the best way to do this?

View A

```
Name (String)
Surname (Sring)
Address (String)
Employed (boolean)
Non-Employed (boolean)
Retired (boolean)
```

Table B

```
Name (String)
Surname (Sring)
Address (String)
Employed Status (String)
```

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, for both input and output.

Comment: Additionally, what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I think you are just wanting an insert statement to insert into TableB and you select the columns from the view. I assume Employed status comes from a case statement against the three other columns in the view. The best way of doing things is hard to answer due to lack of info. The answer might be to not even use the view and use part of the underlying query in the view.  As suggested, post what you have tried and maybe ask for help or ask if there is a better way. Does your “best way” matter that it is a view vs table? If you have multiple solutions/queries, you can look at the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have three flags that seem exclusive, I see no reason to think that they actually are (unless you have some sort of validation).

So, I would concatenate the statuses together:

```
insert into b (name, surname, address, employed_status)
    select name, surname, address,
           stuff(concat(case when employeed = 1 then ', employed' else '' end,
                        case when non_employeed = 1 then ',non_employed' else '' end,
                        case when retired = 1 then ',retired' else '' end
                       ), 1, 1, ''
                )
    from a;
```

Note:  SQL Server does not have a boolean type, so I assume you are using 0/1 encoding for the columns.

Comment: SQL Server uses BIT datatype to represent Boolean values. Consider though that BIT values can be 1, 0 or NULL.

Comment: @Fleshy . . . SQL Server uses a `BIT` to represent a `BIT` or "binary" (ternary with `NULL`).  That is *not* a `boolean`, at least as understood by other databases and most programming languages.  In particular, you cannot assign the result of a boolean operation to a `BIT`.

Comment: Yes, this is why I explicitly said that SQL Server uses BIT to REPRESENT Boolean. Additional info here: http://sqlserverplanet.com/tsql/sql-boolean

Answer (score 0):

I would take a step back and create another table called EmploymentState, into which I would add three rows "1 - Employed", "2 - Unemployed", "3 - Retired". Then add a foreign key to that table from Table A and Table B.

Unless of course, a single person can be in more than one state...in which case you need an intersection table. See https://www.bing.com/search?q=sql+intersection+table&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=sql+intersection+tab&sc=0-20&sk=&cvid=153E23C3D25F461E89F71E106FBF7D66